# Clone/Copy a directory to destination

Tags: php, directory, copy, clone

First of all i have searched and tried many functions but all of them works by copying all the **contents**(not the self source whole folder) of my source directory to destination.

But i want to copy WHOLE DIRECTORY.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED?**

This function copies the contents of folder **copy** of `$source` to folder **New Copy** of destination `$dest`.

```
$source = 'C:\MAMP\htdocs\projectAuru\our/files/copy';
$dest   = 'C:\MAMP\htdocs\projectAuru\our/files/New Copy';

function xcopy($source, $dest, $permissions = 0777)
{
    // Check for symlinks
    if (is_link($source)) {
        return symlink(readlink($source), $dest);
    }

    // Simple copy for a file
    if (is_file($source)) {
        return copy($source, $dest);
    }

    // Make destination directory
    if (!is_dir($dest)) {
        mkdir($dest, $permissions);
    }

    // Loop through the folder
    $dir = dir($source);
    while (false !== $entry = $dir->read()) {
        // Skip pointers
        if ($entry == '.' || $entry == '..') {
            continue;
        }

        // Deep copy directories
        xcopy("$source/$entry", "$dest/$entry", $permissions);
    }

    // Clean up
    $dir->close();
    return true;

}
```

**WHAT I AM LOOKING FOR?**

It should copy my entire directory **copy**(along with all of its files and subfolders) to destination folder **So finally the destination directory should look like afterwards:**

> C:\MAMP\htdocs\projectAuru\our/files/New Copy/**copy**

Comment: Guy Anyone can help me out please???

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is to get the name of the folder that we are copying and mkdir with that name in the Destination and then copy all files to that mkdir destination.

```
             // Get value after last slash and trim trailing slash if exists
            $copyFromFolderName = substr(rtrim($copyFrom, '/'), strrpos(rtrim($copyFrom, '/'), '/') + 1);
            if (!is_dir($base.$copyTo.'/'.$copyFromFolderName)) {
                mkdir($base.$copyTo.'/'.$copyFromFolderName, 0777, true);
                xcopy($base.$copyFrom, $base.$copyTo.'/'.$copyFromFolderName);                      
            }else{
                xcopy($base.$copyFrom, $base.$copyTo.'/'.$copyFromFolderName);                      
            }
```